# Disable com.azure.core.util.logging.ClientLogger in a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, logging

I'm trying to disable the very verbose logging of *com.azure.core.util.logging.ClientLogger* in a spring boot application with regard to eventhubs.

I have following dependencies for azure in a spring boot application

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-eventhubs</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-messaging-eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have the following in my log4j2.xml

```
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.azure.core.util.logging" level="ERROR" />
    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR" />

    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

And I also tried setting following **environment variable** to this value: AZURE_LOG_LEVEL=Error

This all in an attempt to disable the very verbose client logging going on in the console.

yet none of these attempts where successful in disabling the logging.  What else can I do to stop this log horror ?

this is my log dependency resolvement

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-layout-template-json:jar:2.14.1:compile
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out by chance? I am having the same issue and it is driving me NUTS

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the logLevel on "Warning" state?
Check this repo as it might help:
https://github.com/anthonychu/functions-log-suppression.

sample :"logging:logLevel:Function.graphql": "Warning"

Comment: Yes, but changing the error level is not making any difference
<Logger name="com.azure.core.util.logging" level="ERROR" />
seems to be ignored